# Changing date column if condition is met in another column

Tags: r, posixct

I have a large dataset with metadata from images. For some cameras the date was set wrong which i am trying to correct. It seemed pretty straightforward but i can not figure out how to do it without breaking up the dataset. The code below shows essentially what i am trying to do, however, i want to adjust the value inside the complete dataframe without making a subset.

```
library(lubridate)
data <- data.frame(camera= c("1", "1", "2", "2"),
                   date = c("2000-1-02 01:02:03", "2000-1-02 01:02:03","2000-2-02 01:02:03","2000-2-02 01:02:03"))

data$date <- as.POSIXct(data$date)

camera1 <- subset(data, camera== "1")

camera1$date <- camera1$date - months(1)
```

I tried to use the dplyr package and the 'if' function to make it work but it seems like the POSIXct format makes things a little more complicated. Preferably i would make the same time adjustment for multiple cameras at the same time.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? Subtract 1 month from all the dates or subtract different number of months based on `camera` number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you've got several cameras, each with it's own offset from the right time; Camera 1 is a month fast, camera 3 is a month slow.

```
data %>% 
  mutate(date = 
           case_when(camera == 1 ~ date - months(1),
                     camera == 3 ~ date + months(1),
                     TRUE ~ date))

  camera                date
1      1 1999-12-02 01:02:03
2      1 1999-12-02 01:02:03
3      2 2000-02-02 01:02:03
4      2 2000-02-02 01:02:03
```

Comment: You are most welcome!  I know you're new; not long ago I was too.  A little StackOverlfow etiquette: if somebody's answered a question for you, #ACCEPT# their answer.  You do that by clicking the gray checkmark (upper left of the post) and turning it green.  You can also upvote a post with the arrows above the check.

Comment: Thank you for for the explanation! I upvoted but my reputation is not high enough. It needs to be at least 15.